# check if dates are between date range in sql (check without year)

Tags: php, sql, date, date-range

I am developing a holiday guide site!
I am using a MySQL database in which I store the information about hotels.
I have 4 date fields in order to store the 2 possible seasons that works each hotel  (date_from, date_to, date_from_extra, date_to_extra). I store the dates in a format like this: DD/MM, for example: 25/12.

I am trying to check if the date1 of first datepicker of the site and the date2 of the second datepicker are between first range (date_from, date_to) or between second range (date_from_extra, date_to_extra) in the database.

The problem is that I don't use years in database date fields and is difficult to compare dates especially when the first or second season in database doesn't finish at the end of the year but it lasts more, for example (14/11 - 25/02).

Any help?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Guess it's time to start adding years to your date fields? :)

Comment: I think you need to change the column type of your table. Apart from not storing Year in your database, I see another problem. You are storing date in a format like DD/MM. This way you will not be able to use the index of these fields. You should rather store in the format MM/DD. If you store in MM/DD format you can write direct comparison statements eg)  `where ({$date} > date_from and {$date} < date_to) or ({$date} > date_from_extra and {$date} < date_to_extra)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$todayDate = date("Y-m-d");
$check_date= strtotime($todayDate);
```

use this varible to check

```
SELECT table_fiels FROM table_namE WHERE month(check_date)  BETWEEN month($your_db_start_date) AND  month($your_db_end_date) AND day(check_date)  BETWEEN day($your_db_start_date) AND  day($your_db_end_date)
```

Comment: this code cannot work because cannot understand if there are different YEARS in compared dates. for example if the season that the hotel works is 14/11 - 25/02, this code will give me results for 25/02 to 14/11 not for 14/11 to 25/02 of the next year that is the correct